# Django rest - serialize related object

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am using `Django 1.10.5` and `django rest framework 3.5.3` .
I created an model named `Abstract` and it has a related field `User` and a `Minisymposium`.

When I post a new `Abstract` I enter the user's and minisymposium's ID.
But I don't want to get the ID when getting the object, I want to get the serialized object (for example: I post user '2' and get user: `{name: david, id: 2}`

What should I do ?

```
class Abstract(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('submitted', 'Submitted'),
        ('mso_approved', 'MSO Approved'),
        ('congress_org_approved', 'Congress Org Approved'),
        ('approval_email_sent', 'Approval email sent'),
        ('scheduled', 'scheduled'),
        ('denied', 'Denied')
    )
DISPLAY_STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
    ('approved', 'Approved'),
    ('scheduled', 'scheduled'),
    ('denied', 'Denied')
)

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
description = models.TextField(max_length=9000, null=False)
minisymposium = models.ForeignKey(Minisymposium, related_name='abstracts', null=False)
status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=False, default='submitted')
display_status = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=DISPLAY_STATUS_CHOICES, null=False, default='pending')
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id) + ' ' + self.title


class AbstractSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    authors = AuthorSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    minisymposium = MinisymposiumSerializer(read_only=True)

class AbstractViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Abstract.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AbstractSerializer
    filter_fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'status', 'minisymposium',
                     'display_status', 'date', 'user']
    search_fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'status', 'display_status', 'minisymposium__title',
                     'user__username', 'user__first_name', 'user__last_name']
    ordering_fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'status', 'display_status', 'minisymposium__number',
                       'minisymposium__title',
                       'date', 'user__first_name']

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['user'] = request.user.id
        return super(AbstractViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

        class Meta:
            model = Abstract
            fields = ('id', 'date', 'title', 'description', 'status', 'display_status',
                      'url', 'user', 'minisymposium', 'authors')
```

Comment: You can add two fields, `user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(write_only=True, source='user')` and `user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)`. Then for create/update you must use `user_id`.